# EOFError when converting gensim word2vec to binary format

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I have a pretrained embeddings with `word2vec` format in `txt`. I loaded it and then saved it to `.bin`. But I cannot load this embeddings as an `EOFError: unexpected end of input; is count incorrect or file otherwise damaged?`

My original code is:

```py
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(wordfile)
model.save_word2vec_format("file.bin",binary=True,write_header=True)
bin_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("file.bin",binary=True)
```

And I can load this `file.bin` with a limit arguement: `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("file.bin",binary=True, limit=10000)`.

Is there some other process needed when I save embeddings?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance that your `.bin` file has an incorrect leading-count, or the file has been otherwise been damaged/truncated – because that error means the file declared in its header (1st line) a larger number of word-vectors than were found during attempted-load.

So, if you downloaded it or copied it from somewhere, check the original source, to make sure you've got the full file.

Is there a reason you're performing this conversion? The formats are essentialy equivalent, and result in the exact same object-in-Python after loading.

If there's any tiny on-disk size savings in binary-format, you could probably save more by GZIPping the file (which the `.load_word2vec_format()` will also happily decompress, if it sees a trailing `.gz` on the filename).

Comment: The major reason is that the speed of loading `*.bin` is faster than `*.txt`. IThe md5 of downloaded embeddings if same with the original file. But I figure that `len(model.key_to_index) !=len(model.index_to_key)`.  Is  this the reason I got a wrong `.bin` file?

Comment: I'd need to see more details (whole error stack) to know if you're getting the error on initial load, or re-load of your `.bin`. But, on whichever is failing, the file is incomplete/damaged/inconsistent - either the original you started working with, or your local latest copy. I'd be surprised if the loading of a `binary=True` file is much faster than `binary=False` - the code is very similar. What sort of difference did you see? Note that reading a compressed file might speed things up more, too, depending on whether disk-IO or parsing is the real bottleneck.

Comment: Further, depending on why load-speed is so important, there might be other better ways to achieve the real goal. Why is load-speed an issue for your project? How much faster would you want/need it to be?

Comment: My embeddings are about 1.2Gb with 1.3M words. And my server is a little bit slow, the general load speed is about 15 min. But there's no way for my project to clean the embeddings further. As this I turn to convert the txt to binary file for speed up the loading process.

Comment: I still would not expect the `.load_word2vec_format(…, binary=True)` load to be much faster than `.load_word2vec_format(…, binary=False)` load. (1) Did you try it both ways & observe a reliable speedup, and if so, how much? …

Comment: Further, that amount of load-time seems very odd: when working with the 3 million words, 300-dimensional, 3GB `GoogleNews` vectors, I don't recall ever hitting load times even 1/3rd as long as you're reporting. Are you loading over a slow network drive, or even (comapred to SSD) slow spinning hard-drive? In either case, if that's the cause of the slowdown, using a compressed file might help considerably. (2) Once you make sure you have a complete file that loads without error, can you try loading a gzipped or bzipped version of the same file instead, and report the speedup/slowdown observed? …

Comment: OTOH, if the slowdown because you don't have enough RAM to load without using virtual memory (swap memory), that will be slow no matter what, especially if you start doing `.most_similar()` lookups (which necessarily have-to-access all vectors). If the root cause of the slowness is low-memory, only using a system with more memory can help. So understanding the real source of the slowness is essential. So the most important questions to make progress are: (3) Are you loading the vectors from a local disk (HDD or SSD), or from some network source?; (4) How much RAM in the system?

Comment: （1） I only test on first 80K embeds between these two files, about 5s speedup of `.bin`. (2)I  tested on '.bz2`, cost is about double of `.txt` file. (3) Yes, I load it from local HDD. (4) My RAM is 8G. I am not pretty sure, how much the total loaded cost of `.bin` lower than `.txt`. Perhaps, the 5s is caused by some random event.

Comment: Yes, without running/averaging multiple trials, a tiny 5s difference might be more jitter from other influences than a reliable speedup. If it's a local spinning HDD, then IO time is likely a major factor, & trying other compression that offers a different mix of compactness & read-speed may offer some improvement. A binary and a text format file will be exactly the same in-memory after loading (but if all RAM is used by other stuff, both could trigger similar swapping-based slowdowns).

Comment: You may also want to profile the speed of the the Gensim-custom `.save()`/`.load()` methods - especially, trying the `.load()` with the optional memory-mapping mode (which should *not* be used with any compression). But note: that approach reports the load as 'finished' as soon as the core object is loaded, & the vectors memory-mapped (but not yet really loaded) from the file. When you 1st start accessing the vectors, the same loading time will be paid later – for example, when the 1st `.most_similar()` touches all vectors. So be aware in your benchmarking that it may just shift time around.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explaination. The `save()`/ `load()` methods is a good choice for lazy load.